# Bootstrap table tr border top and bottom doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to have my table like here [image]

I try to put border bottom and top for tr to make my code like in the image. One border works but the other doesn't.
Someone on internet said that it's good to put display block for tr, but if I do that all my text will go left side.
In my code I but red and blue border color to see better.
Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

```css
table {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
table tr {
  /*display: block;*/
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table class="table table-striped">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="table-title">Matin</td>
          <td class="table-title">Apres-midi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Lundi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Mardi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Mercredi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jeudi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Vendredi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Samedi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Dimache</td>
          <td>Ferme</td>
          <td>Ferme</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Referring something like this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/2kp6snpe)?

Comment: Not exactly my friend. I suppose to have one border in top of first tr and then each tr should have 2 diff border color in top and bottom

Comment: Well, you can get that by playing with my Fiddle.

Comment: @SorinD. do you need like my answer or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is default styling in Bootstrap that you need to override, either with increased specificity or `!important`.

The code is

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table>tfoot>tr>td, 
.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table>thead>tr>th {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Then you need to override the `border-collapse` property

```css
table {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-collapse: separate !important;
}
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143 vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 4px solid green !important;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="table-title">Matin</td>
      <td class="table-title">Apres-midi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lundi</td>
      <td>08h00-12h00</td>
      <td>13h00-17h00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mardi</td>
      <td>08h00-12h00</td>
      <td>13h00-17h00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mercredi</td>
      <td>08h00-12h00</td>
      <td>13h00-17h00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jeudi</td>
      <td>08h00-12h00</td>
      <td>13h00-17h00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vendredi</td>
      <td>08h00-12h00</td>
      <td>13h00-17h00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Samedi</td>
      <td>08h00-12h00</td>
      <td>13h00-17h00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dimache</td>
      <td>Ferme</td>
      <td>Ferme</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like     border-collapse: separate !important; is doing all the job my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code. The output will give you top border color as red and bottom border color as blue.

```css
table {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
  /*display: block;*/
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  /*background-color: #CC9999;*/
  
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
  /*display: block;*/
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table class="table table-striped">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="table-title">Matin</td>
          <td class="table-title">Apres-midi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Lundi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Mardi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Mercredi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jeudi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Vendredi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Samedi</td>
          <td>08h00-12h00</td>
          <td>13h00-17h00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Dimache</td>
          <td>Ferme</td>
          <td>Ferme</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sorin Do you need like this?

Comment: My friend border red and border blue suppose to be one in top of each other. In the design image is border #fff in top of border #ccc, with table bg #eee.